# Доступ ненадежным приложениям при отправке почты с помощью Gmail

Tags: java, gmail

СОбственно говоря,есть задача отправлять письма с помощью java. Покопавшись в сети, прописал такой код:

```
public class MailSender {

    private final String username = "адрес ящика, с которого отправляем письмо";
    private final String password = "пароль к почтовому ящику";

    public  void MailSending(Message DataMessage){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");


        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(DataMessage.getFrom()));
            message.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(DataMessage.getTo()));
            message.setSubject(DataMessage.getSubject());
            message.setText(DataMessage.getBody());

            Transport.send(message); System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex){ mex.printStackTrace(); }

    }
```

Это дело работает и письма шлет,НО только в том случае, если я в настройках ящика включаю "доступ к ненадежным приложениям"(в противном случае кидает в меня `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`). Я так думаю,что это делать не желательно(безопасность и  все такое), в тоже время решений как обойти эту процедуру я не нашел. Можно ли изменить код так,чтобы проходила аутентификация,доступ ненадежным приложениям был отключен и он не ругался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Сначала включите [двухэтапную аутентификацию](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839)
2. После этого [получите пароль для приложения](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) и используйте его для отправки писем.

Также стоит рассмотреть возможность отправки писем через свой сервер.