# Посыл почты с Gmail после 30 мая(отключение небезопасных методов) .NETCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gmail

До 30 мая я пользовался Gmail для отправки письма с подтверждением со своего сайта.

Выглядело это примерно вот так

```
public static async Task<bool> SendEmail(string email, string subject, string body)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("securemail@gmail.com", "Регистрация");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(email);
        const string fromPassword = "securepass";

        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
        })
        {
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Как видно, использовалась пара mail-пароль для входа. Но с 30 мая гугл отключил этот "небезопасный способ" и теперь надо авторизоваться как то безопасно.

Сам гугл говорит что надо через Oauth2 и consent screen, но это же сервисы для конечного пользователя, когда ты указываешь свою гугл почту и гугл тебе разрешает доступ.

А мне так не надо, мне надо именно со своего .NETCore приложения просто отослать письмо с моей почты на какую то другую, конечный юзер доступа к почте не имеет. Как это сделать?

Comment: [Пароли приложений](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) пробовали? Не уверен, но в теории должно работать через них.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Спасибо, да, дело в них, написал развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как писал @EvgeniyZ, дело было в паролях приложения.

Последовательность действий (частично стало понятно отсюда [Доступ ненадежным приложениям при отправке почты с помощью Gmail](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503829/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-gmail))

1)Включаем в акке, с которого хотим почту слать, двухэтапную аутентификацию - с присылом смс например.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839

2)Генерируем пароль приложения в аккаунте
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Он выглядит как то так "srnyyvqajocnsvdp"

3)И самое главное, то, чего нет в вышеуказанных руководствах - используем этот пароль для доступа в почту точно так же как ранее использовали обычный пароль!

Итоговый код выглядит вот так

```
public static async Task<bool> SendEmail(string email, string subject, string body)
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("securemail@gmail.com", "Регистрация");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(email);
    const string fromPassword = "srnyyvqajocnsvdp"; <- ВОТ ЭТА СТРОЧКА ПОМЕНЯЛАСЬ!

    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
        Timeout = 20000
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
    })
    {
        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
    }

    return true;
}
```