# C# Почта (SMTP, gmail)

Tags: c#, gmail

```cs
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
{
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userEmail.Text, userPassword.Text); // почта и пароль отправителя
    MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
    Message.To.Add(""); // там в скобках писал свою почту
    Message.From = new MailAddress(userEmail.Text, userName.Text);// почта отправителя
    Message.Subject = userSubject.Text;
    Message.Body = userMessage.Text;
    Message.To.Add(""); // там в скобках писал свою почту, то есть чтобы письмо мне отправлялось
    client.Send(Message);
}
```

При отправке сообщения получаю такую ошибку и письмо не пришло мне:

[image: ошибка при отпрвке сообщения]

Comment: `почта и пароль отправителя` - пароль аккаута, или пароль приложения?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - пароль аккаунта

Comment: А нужно приложения. Зайдите в настройки аккаунта, там раздел (вроде) безопасность, найдите "Пароли приложений", сгенерируйте себе новый, его уже и используйте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - зачем? ну отправитель не будет же возиться с генерацией пароля приложения, а потом отправить мне письмо как в службу поддержки.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov - за что минус? Вроде обычное предложение.

Comment: Затем, что это требование Gmail почты....

Comment: EvgeniyZ - то есть надо предупредить об этом пользователю о том что он должен сделать генерацию пароля приложения? Звучит слишком геморрно, даже на сайтах  просто пишешь свою почту пароль и отправляешь письмо в сл.поддержки.

Comment: Не ко мне эти претензии про гемор. Это официальная политика гугла. Вот вам [официальная статья](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) о том, что с 30 мая они отключили вход менее защищенным приложениям, которые не соответствуют их стандартам безопасности (а простой пароль этому не соответствует). А вот вам [дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1417864/220553), где подробно сказано что и где генерироватьва.

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ - погодите, то есть пользователю можно не писать пароль сгенерированный, я могу сгенерить на своей почте и так сработает?

Comment: Один аккаунт = 1 пароль. "Пароль приложения" - замена основного пароля. Там уже я не знаю какую вы задачу решаете. Если у вас сервер, который должен отправить письмо, то на вашей стороне вы указываете один, конкретно свой аккаунт и пароль приложения. Если у вас приложение для клиентов, где с их аккаунтов отсылается, то каждый из них должен сгенерировать пароль приложения и использовать его как замена основному.